# Set env variable in sudo when provisioning Vagrant

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pip, vagrant

I'm trying to install a python package in a Vagrant box that runs in Ubuntu 14 with sudo, this package requires to set an env variable before.

I have tried the following commands, but it did not recognize the env variable when provisioning Vagrant:

`sudo AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes
sudo pip install apache-airflow==1.10.0`

What's the best way to set it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything must be done with one command, else what you have done with the first command would be forgotten when the second command runs:

```
sudo AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes pip install apache-airflow==1.10.0
```

Note: when using the Bourne shell, the syntax

```
VAR1=val1 ... VARn=valN command arg1 ... argN
```

... runs `command arg1 ... argN` with all variables VAR1, ..., VARN added as its environment variables.